# Unit testing object to object mappings

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have been asked to assist in coding a number of MS Unit Tests for a number of object to object mappings. Can anyone advise what level of testing is appropriate to test the mapping functionality?

Shown below is some (*non production*) sample code.

```
public class Foo
{
    public enum FooType
    {
        Active, Deleted, Open, Closed
    }

    public bool IsConditionMet { get; set; }
    public FooType SimpleType { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string SomeCondition { get; set; }
    public string SomeAbbreviatedType { get; set; }
}

public static class BarMapper
{
    // sample to mapping code 
    public static Foo Map(Bar bar)
    {
        var foo = new Foo
                      {
                          IsConditionMet = bar.SomeCondition.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      };

        // this is sample code and not used in production
        switch (bar.SomeAbbreviatedType)
        {
            case "A":
                foo.SimpleType = Foo.FooType.Active;
                break;

            case "D":
                foo.SimpleType = Foo.FooType.Deleted;
                break;

            case "O":
                foo.SimpleType = Foo.FooType.Open;
                break;

            case "C":
                foo.SimpleType = Foo.FooType.Closed;
                break;
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for a definition of a unit test, how to write one or an explanation on TDD but specifically looking for an example of what unit tests you'd write given the above example.

Note: Unfortunately due to the nature of the source data using a mapping framework like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) will not add any value to the project.

**Update: This is my example on the appropriate level of testing.**

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsMappingToIsConditionMetCorrect()
{
    var fooIsConditionMetShouldBeTrue = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeCondition = "Y" });
    var fooIsConditionMetShouldBeFalse = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeCondition = "N" });
    var fooIsConditionMetShouldBeFalse_BecauseSomeConditionIsInvalid = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeCondition = "SOMETHING" });

    Assert.IsTrue(fooIsConditionMetShouldBeTrue);
    Assert.IsFalse(fooIsConditionMetShouldBeFalse);
    Assert.IsFalse(fooIsConditionMetShouldBeFalse_BecauseSomeConditionIsInvalid);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestsCanBuild()
{
    var fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeA = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeAbbreviatedType = "A" });
    var fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeD = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeAbbreviatedType = "D" });
    var fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeO = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeAbbreviatedType = "O" });
    var fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeC = BarMapper.Map(new Bar { SomeAbbreviatedType = "C" });

    Assert.AreSame(Foo.FooType.Active, fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeA);
    Assert.AreSame(Foo.FooType.Deleted, fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeD);
    Assert.AreSame(Foo.FooType.Open, fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeO);
    Assert.AreSame(Foo.FooType.Closed, fooAbbreviatedTypeShouldBeC);

    // TODO: test for an incorrect "SomeAbbreviatedType" property value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests look fairly reasonably (when you implement TODO: test for an incorrect "SomeAbbreviatedType" property value), there is not much more you can test. One thing I would personally look into a bit more is error handling, e.g. is it valid for Bar to have SomeAbbreviatedType empty? Maybe should it be an enum, etc.? But from testing perspective its alright.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my approach

Answer (score 0):

What you need is test coverage data, which measures the ratio of tested code to total code.  WHile your exhibited test may provide a high ratio, other than guesswork you have no way of knowing that.   You can get accurate data from a test coverage tool.

Test coverage tools for many languages (including Java, C#, C++, C and COBOL) can be found at [Test Coverage Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage).